# C++: Unsure if code is multithreadable

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl, gpgpu

I'm working on a small piece of code which takes a very large amount of time to complete, so I was thinking of multithreading it either with pthread (which I hardly understand but think I can master a lot quicker) or with some GPGPU implementation (probably OpenCL as I have an AMD card at home and the PCs I use at my office have various NVIDIA cards)

```
   while(sDead < (unsigned long) nrPoints*nrPoints) {

    pPoint1 = distrib(*rng);
    pPoint2 = distrib(*rng);

    outAxel = -1;

    if(pPoint1 != pPoint2) {

      point1 = space->getPointRef(pPoint1);
      point2 = space->getPointRef(pPoint2);

      outAxel = point1->influencedBy(point2, distThres);

      if(outAxel == 0 || outAxel == 1)
    sDead++;
      else
    sDead = 0;

    }

    i++;
  }
```

Where distrib is a uniform_int_distribution with `a` = 0 and b = `nrPoints-1`.
For clarity, here is the structure I'm working with:

```
class Space{
  vector<Point> points
  (more stuff)
}

class Point {
  vector<Coords> coordinates
  (more stuff)
}

struct Coords{
  char Range
  bool TypeOfCoord
  char Coord
}
```

The length of `coordinates` is the same for all `Point`s and `Point[x].Coord[y].Range == Point[z].Coord[y].Range` for all `x`, `y` and `z`. The same goes for `TypeOfCoord`.

Some background: during each run of the `while` loop, two randomly drawn `Point`s from `space`  are tested for interaction.  `influencedBy()` checks whether or not `point1` and `point2` are close enough to eachother (distance is dependent on some metric but it boils down to similarity in `Coord`. If the distance is smaller than distThres, interaction is possible) to interact. Interaction means that one of the `Coord` variables which doesn't equal the corresponding `Coord` in the other object is flipped to equal it. This decreases the distance between the `Point`s but also changes the distance of the changed `point` to every other `point` in `Space`, hence my question of whether or not this is multithreadable. As I said, I'm a complete newbie to multithreading and I'm not sure if I can safely implement a function that chops this up, so I was looking for your input. Suggestions are also very welcome.

E: The influencedby() function (and the functions it in turn calls) can be found [here](http://pastebin.ca/2697008). Functions that I did not include, such as getFeature() and getNrFeatures() are tiny and cannot possibly contribute much. Take note that I used generalised names for objects in this question but I might mess up or make it more confusing if I replace them in the other code, so I've left the original names there. For the record:

```
Space = CultSpace
Point = CultVec
Points = Points
Coordinates = Feats
Coords = Feature
TypeOfCoord = Nomin
Coord = Trait
```

Comment: For a useful answer, runtime and behavior (including used algorithm) of `distrib`, `getPointRef` and `influencedBy` are probably critical. Always try for better algorithms before hauling out the big iron or multithreading.

Comment: what's i++ ? Could you show the complete iteration ? From a first look, the code section depends on the results of itself, so it's hardly thread-able but it may be thread-able in a more top level context...

Comment: If the Points have a fixed number of coordinates, using a vestor there is severe overkill, which you have to pay for. Use a fixed array instead.

Comment: @Deduplicator: distrib and getPointRef are both functions that take hardly any time, influencedby() is a slightly more complicated function but it boils down to only changing the value, like I said. I've looked into optimising it already, removing error checking if statements and the such, but very little time can be saved anymore.
As for thanking people, I'm sorry, I didn't realise I had to click the tick to finalise things, I've done that now.
As for the use of a vector, the size is the same across all points in the entire space, but this can differ per space (I read in spaces from a CSV)

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini: i is simply a counter that is returned by the function that encompasses this piece of code, it is not involved in any calculation whatsoever. I was considering multithreading the entire function (this function is called 20-200 times depending on parameters) but that may cause problems with available memory (the space can get quite big). I used to be able to simply open up the entire program multiple times but I've added some functionality since that time which relies on values calculated from each time the function is called, so that's no longer an option.

Comment: So, all three are constant time? Did you make your measurements near the end or the beginning of your execution?

Comment: @Deduplicator: distrib is simply uniform_int_distribution, and as I said below, getPointRef returns only a pointer and does nothing else, it's a separate function because the points are private. I guess I can post influencedby() in my question.

Comment: Did you check how often this loop is executed until `sDead` hits the threshold? It could be as simple as that...

Comment: @laune of course it depends on both the dimension of Points and of Coordinates, but for reference: I've currently got a sample of 625 points with 100 coords taking on average 30 million executions of the loop. If memory serves, another set with 2000 points and 81 coords took on average 300 million. There's no way around it taking this long (once sDead hits the threshold I can be fairly sure that no interactions are possible anymore, and I require equilibrium to continue), that I know, but that's why I'm asking if it's possible to at least speed it up using parallelisation.

Comment: Maybe I still haven't understood it completely, but let's see. We have points in a space, and a distance metric. And you need to find all (or as close to "all" as reasonably possible) pairs with dist < threshold. But you are using some sort of Monte-Carlo-Method?! -- I'm sure that there is a way of ordering the points so that a much better solution is possible. E.g., order along one axis (x), and investigate all pairs where |x1-x2| is less than threshold.

Comment: What I'm basically modelling is people (`Points`) whose opinions (`Trait`s) on subjects (`Feature`s) are close enough (under `distThres`) to say that they would be willing to interact with one another (one person convinces the other of an opinion they differ in), so simply ordering a priori isn't too useful as the ordering changes while the model is working.

I also considered splitting the space up in noninteracting subspaces but my supervisor told me such a feat is not possible. In any case it wouldn't always help, if distThres was large enough there would be only one space anyway.

Comment: Well, then bite the bullet or buy more CPU power.

Answer (score 1):

(Choosing "Answer" because the format permits better presentation. Not quite what your're asking for, but let's clarify this first.)

**Later**

How often is the loop executed until this condition becomes true?

```
while(sDead < (unsigned long) nrPoints*nrPoints) {
```

Probably not a big gain, but:

```
pPoint1 = distrib(*rng);
do {
   pPoint2 = distrib(*rng);
while( pPoint1 == pPoint2 );


outAxel = -1;
```

How costly is getPointRef? Linear search in Space?

```
point1 = space->getPointRef(pPoint1);
point2 = space->getPointRef(pPoint2);

outAxel = point1->influencedBy(point2, distThres);
```

Is it really necessary to recompute the "distance of the changed point to every other point in Space" immediately after a "flip"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. getPointRef simply returns a pointer to Points[pos], so it can't be a detriment compared to the rest. The distance isn't actually recalculated for each point after it's flipped, I just added that to make clear what happens.

Comment: This "returns a pointer" was clear to me. Read what I asked, please! How big is Space, how is the point located?

Comment: I know what you mean, and I thought I answered it. Literally the only code in `getPointRef(pos)` is `return &Points[pos]`. The space can be anything between `Points.size()` = 20 and `Coordinates.size()` = 100 for quick code checking computation and `Points.size()` = 2500 (if I can optimise this, maybe even 50000) and `Coordinates.size()` = ±500.